# How can I "pinch" an element containing text smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

#### What I'm trying to do

My goal is to transition a list so that when an item is clicked, it smoothly rises to the top of the list, becoming the title (see example). Realistically, a menu UI would appear below it. I can transition the height of all elements except the one clicked to smoothly animate it to the top of the list. That works! But the text, when the container becomes too small, the text of course just disappears. My intention is for the text to pinch too.

---

#### What I've tried

So of course I must use a transform. However a transform pinches the container visually, but doesn't physically change the space that it inhabits, so the clicked list item doesn't rise to the top.

Finally, when I try to simultaneously transform a container and change its height to zero, the result is not as expected. The change in height is taken into account by the transformation, and also the text still just disappears at this point.

Additionally, gaps seem to form between the items since the transform is actually taking the height change into account, making them transform visually faster than their sizes can shrink!

---

#### My Question

How can I simultaneously transform a container and physically lower its height to zero in a **smooth, fluent** way, without the text disappearing at any point until it is **pinched** to zero height (and without gaps appearing between the items mid-transition)?

---

#### Example:

```js
//name variables containing JQuery $...

$('.container').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  $allContainersExceptThis = $('.container').not(this);
  if (!this.isSelected) {
    $allContainersExceptThis.css({
      'transform': 'scaleY(0)'
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'orange',
      'color': '#FF3300'
    });
    this.isSelected = true;
  } else {
    $allContainersExceptThis.css({
      'transform': ''
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '',
      'color': ''
    });
    this.isSelected = false;
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
 html,
body,
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 2in;
  height: 3in;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
.wrapper > .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.6in;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}
.wrapper .container:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.wrapper .container:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper > .container > .name {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="containerOne" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container One</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerTwo" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Two</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerThree" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Three</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerFour" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: visible`?

Comment: I've posted an answer, I'm not sure if it does what you want but you can always change it a bit. It does do both the transform and height at the same time, which in general solves your problem.

Comment: @AlbertXing See my comment on your answer. Overflow visible works better than I predicted, but I'm not sure how to overcome those gaps that form in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you were looking for?
It's a combination of `overflow: visible` with your transform.

I've slowed it down quite a bit to show the animation more clearly.

**EDIT:** The gap problem was solved by changing top and bottom margins, instead of height - since changing the height would make the scale transform even smaller than it was.

```js
//name variables containing JQuery $...

$('.container').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  $allContainersExceptThis = $('.container').not(this);
  if (!this.isSelected) {
    $allContainersExceptThis.css({
      'transform': 'scaleY(0)',
      'margin-top': '-0.3in',
      'margin-bottom': '-0.3in'
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'orange',
      'color': '#FF3300'
    });
    this.isSelected = true;
  } else {
    $allContainersExceptThis.css({
      'transform': '',
      'margin-top': '',
      'margin-bottom': ''
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '',
      'color': ''
    });
    this.isSelected = false;
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
 html,
body,
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 2in;
  height: 3in;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
.wrapper > .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.6in;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 3s, background-color 3s, color 3s, margin-top 3s, margin-bottom 3s;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
.wrapper .container:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.wrapper .container:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper > .container > .name {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="containerOne" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container One</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerTwo" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Two</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerThree" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Three</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerFour" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that overflow shown actually works better than I expected, however, can this be done without those gaps forming between the items?

Comment: @JonathanTodd Okay, I think I figured it out. You can't change the height as you change the scaling, because that would make the scaled height even smaller. So instead, we change the top and bottom margins to move each container. See updated answer above.

Comment: Awesome! That's very creative thanks for your time! You should add that bit about fixing the gaps into your answer's explanation since I edited that problem into my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.slideUp()` , `.slideDown()`

```js
//name variables containing JQuery $...

$('.container').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
  $allContainersExceptThis = $('.container').not(this);
  if (!this.isSelected) {
    $allContainersExceptThis.slideUp({
        duration: 500,
        done: function() {
          $(this).css('transform', 'scaleY(0)')
        }
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'orange',
      'color': '#FF3300'
    });
    this.isSelected = true;
  } else {
    $allContainersExceptThis.slideDown({
        duration: 500,
        start: function() {
          $(this).css('transform', 'scaleY(1)')
        }
    });
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': '',
      'color': ''
    });
    this.isSelected = false;
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
 html,
body,
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 2in;
  height: 3in;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
.wrapper > .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.6in;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}
.wrapper .container:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.wrapper .container:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper > .container > .name {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="containerOne" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container One</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerTwo" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Two</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerThree" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Three</div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerFour" class="container">
    <div class="name">Container Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```